# Redis module ReJSON with OSS redis

Tags: redis, open-source, redisjson

I saw here that there are three kinds of redis modules from the link below.

https://redislabs.com/community/redis-modules-hub/

However, I want to use ReJSON along with OSS Redis. Is it possible and has anyone tried it and if yes, is there a source to refer to for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedisJSON (former known as ReJSON) is fully supporting OSS Redis, see http://redisjson.io